# How to do a DOM based XSS attack? How to place an element using this vulnerability?

Tags: javascript, html

I am supposed to make a DOM based XSS attack what means that I insert a HTML element with javascript code. (for example an `<iframe>`)

I have this search box in the html file:

`<span id="searchValue" [innerHTML]="searchValue"></span>`

What is the `[innerHTML]="searchValue"` property does? How can I use this search input to place an element in the HTML code?

I know in javascript you can change the value between the element opening and closing tag with innerHTML, but here I have no idea what it does.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this Angular? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34424375/1871033

Comment: I'm assuming a homework question, so I'll just provide a hint... The issue that is trying to be conveyed is that whatever gets typed into the search box is squirted, without validation, directly into the DOM as a child of the span (most likely by a poorly written backend). Say you typed `<strong>my name is stacktrace2234</strong>`, then you could format your search term to be bold when it is shown back to you. There exist other tags too, which might lead to far worse mischief.

Comment: Yes, it is an angular application that I have to use.